# Django how to allow people to connect my file in the application

Tags: python, django

Currently, I am building the Django on the local. I developed the program to allow people download and reconnect some files. But now I am using the static address. If I set up the Django on the website. What should I do? Do I need to set up my base url and how? Do I need to set the address in the view.py and urls.py?

Comment: Sorry, it's really unclear what you are asking. Have you done the Django tutorial?

Comment: You really need to clarify what you mean, but short answer: if you used {% url 'foo'%}'s in templates instead of hardcoding /foo (or worse http://localhost/foo), django will make the URL's work off the base you're running (though I've seen issues where if you have the link be for http://server/mydjangoapp/, things are "weird" if a user goes to http://server/mydjangoapp (without the trailing slash))

Comment: Thanks, I think Nginx probably is able to solve my problem. I am trying and will post the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx will solve it problem. Set static folder in the Nginx.